# Migrating objects in GAE data store with Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an application that naturally as it grows various data model classes need to change attributes (add, rename, remove, etc). In MySQL I would just run a set of queries against the data store that would alter the schemas and the data.

I don't understand what is the correct approach to do with GAE's data store. My application on the server side is written in Java.

Specifically, I would like to know how to:

1) Rename a field on an existing object
2) Add a new field on an existing object (I think this happen automatically on new objects)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine) in managing the datastore; it also has the ability to [update schemas of existing models](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Migrating_Schemas) quite easily.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. In this case, if I read the documentation right, Objectify basically makes it a little easier to do object-object migration at load/save time or to do a bulk migration. I guess this is a bit of the downside of having a schema-less data store, you have to think through the reality of having multiple object versions in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has recently created a tool that would probably do what you need: http://code.google.com/p/entity-console/